# Good design for out-of-core computations in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, out-of-memory, dask

I'm working a script which loads in time series weather data (1 minutes resolution) at various gridpoints, and then for each time calculates an estimate of the ground temperature. Ideally, i would like the script to run simply as:

```
for each gridpoint in gridpoint_list:
     for each time in time_range:
          wth = get_weather(gridpoint, time)
          ground_temperature = calc_temperature(wth)
          ...
```

The weather data does **not fit into memory**, so I can't load it all into a pandas dataframe in the beginning of the script. I would like for these out-of-core things to be handled behind the scenes, so I don't have to rewrite the script to process in batches of e.g. days, since e I will be doing this kind of operation frequently in other scripts as well.

Is there a good solution for this (would dask be useful for this instead of pandas)?

EDIT: The weather data is stored as a partitioned Parquet dataset.

Comment: without knowing how your weather data structure is stored, I can't suggest a specific piece of code. However, I would suggest using some kind of generator instead of loading all the data at once. [f.readlines](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) does a similar thing. Rather than opening a whole file, it gives the output line by line

Comment: @jrmylow The data is stored as Parquet (i edited the post, thanks). I was also thinking of making some generator, but it would be nice if there was a framework for such solutions already.

Comment: Dask loads parquet by partitions from parquet, out-of-core. Did you try?

Comment: Pandas you have to live with in-memory, like mdurant suggested, dask would be good fit and light-weight